# How can I run cucumber tests with options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I need json reports after cucumber test. When I run `cucumber -format json -o cucumber.json` all is ok. But when I run:

`bundle exec rake cucumber -f json -o cucumber.json`

Error: `invalid option: -o`

`bin/rails cucumber -f json -o cucumber.json`

Error: `invalid option: -o`

I try different variants with --format, -f, -o, --out, but get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`bundle exec cucumber -- -f json -o cucumber.json`

or:

`bin/rails cucumber -- -f json -o cucumber.json`

The double dash should ensure the params are passed to `cucumber`, not `bundle` or `exec`